# Подключение моделей, не зная namespace

Tags: yii2

В первой версии можно было без проблем передать имя класса в качестве параметра, и yii подключит нужный класс (например, в админке). Во второй же версии нужно указывать namespace, чтобы использовать модель.

Всё просто, если все модели лежат в одной папке, а если модели используются в разных модулях с разным пространством имён, то уже сложности.

Скажите, что можно сделать, чтобы контроллер мог подключать любую модель без явного указания пространства имён? Имена классов уникальны в пределах проекта, за исключением папки vendors.

Comment: @frgs ничего нельзя сделать, разве что собственный обработчик, который по getModel($name) будет выплевать нужный инстанс. Если имя уникально, то в чем проблема ввести его и дождаться автокомплита, который сам предложит ипортировать класс?

Answer (score 1):

Если нельзя все модели поместить в один неимспейс, остается только передавать в качестве параметра имя класса вместе с неимспейс: someFunction('\app\models\SomeModel');